# Как обьеденить два словаря и подсчитать, сколько каждого ключа?

Tags: python, python-3.x, словари

Нужно объединить два ключа в один и посчитать сумму. Один код не работает, а другой странно работает:

```
stuff = {'cold coin': 42, 'rupe': 1, 'dagger': 1, 'sword': 1}
dragonLoot = {'cold coin': 3, 'robe': 1, 'sword': 1}
print('Inventory')

def addToInventory(inventory, addedItem):
    for k, v in inventory.items():
        if k == k in addedItem.items():
            allValue = v.inventory + v.addedItem
            print(k + ' ' + str(allValue))
addToInventory(stuff, dragonLoot)
```

он, к сожалению, не работает...

```
def addToInventory(inventory, addedItem):
    for k, v in inventory.items():
        if k == k in addedItem:
           total = v + v
            print(k + ' ' + str(total))
        elif k not in inventory:
            print(k + ' ' + str(v))
        else:
            print(k + ' ' + str(v))
addToInventory(stuff, dragonLoot)
```

Этот выводит не сумму ключей с 2 словарей, а если ключи сходяться, то он сумирует количество с 1 словаря

PS И еще один вопрос: возможно ли обьеденить, если записать например:

```
dragonLoot = {'cold coin', 'cold coin', 'cold coin', 'robe', 'sword'}
```

Comment: Что вот это за конструкция вообще: `if k == k in addedItem.items()` в чём её смысл? )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для объединения словарей с подсчетом можно воспользоваться методом [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) из collections:

```
from collections import Counter
```

Для вашего случая:

```
stuff = {'cold coin': 42, 'rupe': 1, 'dagger': 1, 'sword': 1}
dragon_loot = {'cold coin': 3, 'robe': 1, 'sword': 1}

new_stuff = Counter(stuff) + Counter(dragon_loot)
print(new_stuff)
```

В результате получите объект Counter:

```
Counter({'cold coin': 45, 'sword': 2, 'rupe': 1, 'dagger': 1, 'robe': 1})
```

который можно перевести снова в словарь:

```
new_stuff_dict = dict(new_stuff)
print(new_stuff_dict)
```

код выведет:

```
{'cold coin': 45, 'rupe': 1, 'dagger': 1, 'sword': 2, 'robe': 1}
```

ps в функции:

```
def stuff_count(stuff, loot):
    from collections import Counter

    new_stuff = Counter(stuff) + Counter(loot)
    return dict(new_stuff)
```

Comment: спасибо, да я так делал, но я бы хотел через функцию, где dragonLoot может быть различным и мы его просто в функцию подставляем и готово. Или это слишком запарно ?

Comment: "dragonLoot может быть различным"... насколько различным?

Comment: @RostikLugovyy фунция - две-три строчки... добавил

Comment: @Jaco_oS спасибо)) я имеел веду, что не только его могут убивать, но и других )) извиняюсь за вопрос, но может дадите совет, где можно найти различные задания для питон, 4 день его учу по учебнику, но заданий там не много :( )

Comment: def stuff_count(stuff, loot) принимает два параметра, передайте текущее имущество и лут от моба, в ответ получите обновленное имущество...

Answer (score 3):

Это очень странная конструкция:

```
if k == k in addedItem.items():
```

Вы там скорее всего хотите проверить что-то такое:

```
if k in addedItem: # короткий вариант для if k in addedItem.keys() в Python3
```